# Create list of column from one table where only ID's from other table have only a 1 value and not 0 from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, listagg

I have a bunch of different tables I'm using to get info on the the products with labels that only have "use" 0 from another label and filtering on the group_id:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Product (id, color) AS
  SELECT 234322, 'green' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 636634, 'blue'  FROM DUAL;
```

Product_label

| product_id | label_id |
| --- | --- |
| 234322 | special |
| 636634 | nosale |
| 234322 | regular |
| 636634 | special |
| 232897 | nosale |
| 232897 | regular |

Labels

| id | label_name | use | region_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | special | 1 | 567 |
| 325 | nosale | 0 | 567 |
| 690 | regular | 0 | 891 |

Region

| id | group_id |
| --- | --- |
| 567 | 55 |
| 478 | 55 |
| 785 | 55 |

Product_region

| product_id | region_id |
| --- | --- |
| 234322 | 567 |
| 636634 | 567 |
| 234322 | 785 |
| 636634 | 478 |

The result I'm trying to get is to only get the product_id with the listed names of the label, but for use = 0 for a specific group_id:

| product_id | label_id | use | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 232897 | nosale, regular | 0 | 55 |

How do I get the right results without showing the product_id's that have a label with use '1' and with '0'? What I've come up with so far gives me the listed label names but how to filter only product_id's without any label with use '1'?

````
LISTAGG(DISTINCT C.LABEL_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B.PRODUCT_ID)
OVER (PARTITION BY B.PRODUCT_ID) AS NAMES,
LISTAGG(DISTINCT C.USE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B.PRODUCT_ID)
OVER (PARTITION BY B.PRODUCT_ID) AS SELECTED

FROM PRODUCT A

LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_LABEL B
ON A.ID = B.PRODUCT_ID

LEFT JOIN LABELS C
ON B.LABEL_ID = C.ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN REGION D
ON C.REGION_ID = D.ID

WHERE D.GROUP_ID = '55';```
````

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data so that we can just copy-paste and execute them rather than having to reformat your data if we want to use it.

Comment: I've changed your data for the `Product` table into a `CREATE TABLE` statement to give you an example. All you need to do is change the rest into similar syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear why you are using analytic functions. You appear to want to aggregate and can use brackets to specify the precedence of the joins and add a filter for `use = 0` in the join condition so that the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` stays an `OUTER JOIN` (currently, your `WHERE D.GROUP_ID = '55'` filter changes all the `LEFT` joins to `INNER` joins as it is impossible for that filter to be true during an `OUTER` join):

```sql
SELECT p.id AS product_id,
       LISTAGG(l.label_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY l.label_name)
         AS label_names,
       MAX(l.use) AS use,
       MAX(r.group_id) AS group_id
FROM   product p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         product_label pl
         INNER JOIN labels l
         ON pl.label_id = l.label_name
         INNER JOIN region r
         ON l.region_id = r.id
       )
       ON     p.id  = pl.product_id
          AND l.use = 0
          AND r.group_id = 55
GROUP BY
       p.id
```

*Note: this is untested because your sample data is not in an easily usable format. If you provide the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements in the question (rather than having the data in tables) then it can be tested.*

Comment: I'm gonna give this a try, thanks a lot. I'll provide sample data next time, but have never done that. I would probably need another question here to know how to do that to be honest :D

Comment: @Lvh I edited your question and gave you an example for the `product` table. If you want more examples then just look at most of my past answers as they tend to include the sample data used during testing.